# Trying To Figure Out CSS Animations

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to animate a headline element in CSS so that when hovered it rotates the text forward. I've read through loads of tutorials and managed to get it rotating clockwise (or anticlockwise) but not how I want (forward, as if it's spinning towards me).

A great example of the effect I am after is displayed at http://disruptltd.com/ when you hover the navigation links.

If anyone could tell me if that's possible using CSS or any information on how to achieve that effect I'd be massively appreciative

Here is the closest I've come so far, using this code :

```
.navigation h1:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin-reverse {
  0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-reverse {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes spin-reverse {
  0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin-reverse {
  0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
@keyframes spin-reverse {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-359deg); }
}
```

I've also made a jfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qzxbd5fz/

So basically I want the effect to look like it's spinning towards me, similar to a slot machine as opposed to this clock hand spinning style effect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try your luck using scale transform

Comment: thanks dude, will look into it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather simple example I have deviced, by slightly modifying your markup. As the slot machine spinning effect requires depth, it means that we need some kind of wrapping so that we can declare a `perspective` value to the parent element:

```
<h1><span>SITE LOGO</span></h1>
```

The slot machine effect involves the following:

1. Giving depth to the element, so that when it's facing backwards (away from you), it is further away from the screen/viewer
2. Using scale the resize the element, since we are going to translate the element on the Z axis to give the depth effect

The code is as follow, and a sample fiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qzxbd5fz/2/. To better demonstrate the effect I have opted to use CSS transition, but you can always convert it back to animation.

```
h1 {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 30px;
    perspective: 100px;
}
h1 span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(50px) scale(0.5);
}
h1:hover span {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg) translateZ(50px) scale(0.5);
}
```

More importantly, you can use `backface-visibility: hidden` on the `<span>` element to prevent the text from showing through when rotated -180deg away from the viewer along the X axis.

---

### A simpler solution

After seeing that OP has clarified what kind of effect he wants to see, perhaps a simple translation trick with pseudo-elements will do fine.

The thing is that in order to have the effect as mentioned on the sample page linked, you will need to duplicate the site logo text in one way or another — I don't recommend using HTML to do so, because it has no semantic meaning (imagine a search engine reading two "Home" links). Instead, you can use either pseudo-elements (which require updating when you change the logo titles) or JS to duplicate the text. Here I have decided to use pseudo-elements for a pure CSS approach.

View the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qzxbd5fz/3/

Again, use the following markup:

```
<h1><span>SITE LOGO</span></h1>
```

For your CSS:

```
h1 {
    background: #000;
    font-family: Arial;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 span {
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
h1 span, h1 span::after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
h1 span::after {
    content: 'SITE LOGO';
    color: #1ddfb3;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(-100%, 100%, 0);
}
h1:hover span {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for the response. I don't know what I'm missing but I've loaded your jfiddles on a couple of different machines and nothing happens. Even on different browsers, there doesn't seem to be noticeable transition?

Comment: @YoungForch You should add your own vendor prefixes. I am only using `-webkit-`, but you should prepend all vendor prefixes to cover all grounds.

Comment: Terry, you are a legend :) Thank you for your help it looks great, and is going to add a really quality touch the site I'm trying to build

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/qzxbd5fz/1/

This is what I've added

```
h1{
    -webkit-transition:font-size 3s ;
}
h1:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:50px;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks a bunch for that and it looks awesome. I think I didn't explain clearly, I'm looking for the text to be rotating forward (think rotissirie chicken lol), disruptltd.com have a good example in the navigation on their site

really appreciate the help though :)

Comment: @YoungForch i'm sorry could you explain it again

Comment: @YoungForch i checked the site but which effect do you want there are so many of them